# Tree Identification - shaggy bark

Tags: identification, trees

My sister bought a new house this year.  There's a tree in the yard that we can't identify.  It's located in Mid-Michigan in zone 5a.  The soil is mixed with rocks and sand.

The tree has shaggy bark similar to Shagbark Hickory, but the tree produceds a catkin and not a nut.  The leaves (4 or 5 inches long) are pointed ovals with serations.

What is it?

[image: Trunk]
[image: Leaf and branch]
[image: Leaf and Catkin]
[image: More leaves]
[image: Tree shape]
[image: Better Picture of leaf and catkin]

Pictures taken in mid Sept, 2018.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elms don't have catkins and have alternate leaves and U. thomasii is quite uncommon in cultivation (I've never seen it in the trade). I think it's more likely to be an Ostrya, perhaps O. virginiana. The bark on your tree is somewhat shaggier than I would've expected, though. Since the flowers and fruits are quite distinctive, these photos should help with the ID. Please let me know if I'm incorrect and I'll delete this post to clean up the site.

[Flowers (O. virginiana)](https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2837/13715027254_12f2a7003a_z.jpg)

[Fruits (O. carpinifolia, but representative of the genus)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Ostrya_carpinifolia_2.jpg)

[Leaves (O. carpinifolia)](http://irapl.altervista.org/cpm/albums/bot-units156/ostrya-carpinifolia70045.jpg)

[Form (O. carpinifolia)](https://www.guiaverde.com/files/plant/ARB_146.jpg)

[Bark (O. carpinifolia)](https://www.bomengids.nl/2015/images/Hopbeuk__Ostrya_carpinifolia__Hop_hornbeam__Gemeine_Hopfenbuche__Charme-Houblon/bast-bark-rinde-ecorse-corteza/Hopbeuk__Ostrya_carpinifolia__Hop_hornbeam__Gemeine_Hopfenbuche__Charme-Houblon1M.jpg)

Comment: Bark almost looks like a silver maple, but that's absurd.

Comment: The catkins are still tight at this time.  When they open up I can compare the fruit to your picture.  I'll also try to get another picture.

Comment: I found http://www.uky.edu/hort/American-Hophornbeam that appears to be a match to our tree.  I also added a better picture of leaf and catkin.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Here's a nice identification guide for Ostrya Virginiana https://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=62#:~:text=Flower%3A%20Species%20is%20monoecious%3B%20males,%3A%20Very%20distinctive%2C%20resembling%20hops.

Answer (score 0):

It is Ostrya virginiana. Eastern Hop Hornbeam. Not to be confused with American Hornbeam. An incredibly strong and hard wood. One of the strongest in the states. They used to use it to make hockey sticks before they started using composites.